# How can I save a quanteda dictionary as a yaml file?

Tags: r, quanteda

I have created a custom dictionary using the dictionary function from the Quanteda package in R and I would like to save it as a YAML file for future use.

For now, I have the R script where I created the dictionary and I have saved the dictionary as a RDS object. I have also converted the quanteda-format dictionary into yaml format using the `as.yaml` function. So far so good.

But then, when I try to save it, using the base `save` function, the resulting file is all jammed.

So, here is a short version of my process:

```r
    dict <- quanteda::dictionary(list(
      Key1 = list(
        SubKey1.1 = c("a", "ab", "az"),
        SubKey1.2 = c("b", "bc", "bz")
        ),
      Key2 = list(
        SubKey2.1 = c("c", "cd", "cy"),
        SubKey2.2 = c("d", "de", "dw")
        )
      ))

dict_yml <- as.yaml(dict)
save(dict_yml, file = "dict.yml")
```

Could anyone tell me how to properly save the dict_yml object into a YAML file?

Comment: I guess what you need is `yaml::write_yaml(dict, "dict.yml")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as.yaml()` function in **quanteda** creates a character object that is your dictionary in yaml format.  To write this to a file:

```
cat(dict_yml, file = “dict.yml”)
```

Note also that in the forthcoming update (>= 2.0.2) we have added a `dictionary_edit()` function that opens the dictionary in yaml format in an editor, and returns the edited dictionary to R - if that is why you wanted to save it.

Comment: Thanks Ken! That's exactly the answer I was looking for! Looking forward to the update!